# SSMS Addin Not working on SSMS 2016

Tags: plugins, ssms

I wrote an Addin for MSSQL 2014. Now i upgrate my addin for MSSQL 2016 but it doesn't work. SSMS doesn't load my Addin.

I copied my Addin file to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins\".

My Addin File is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<Extensibility xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AutomationExtensibility">
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio</Name>
        <Version>*</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <Addin>
        <FriendlyName>BOA.Addins.MSSQL</FriendlyName>
        <Description>BOA.Addins.MSSQL</Description>
        <AboutBoxDetails>Nusret Parlak\r\nEnterprise Architecture\r\nCopyright (c) 2016  Nusret Parlak</AboutBoxDetails>
        <AboutIconData></AboutIconData>     <Assembly>D:\Projects\BOA.Addin\BOA.Addins.12\v2.2.0\BOA.Addins.MSSQL\bin\Debug\BOA.Addins.MSSQL.dll</Assembly>
        <FullClassName>BOA.Addins.MSSQL.Connect</FullClassName>
        <LoadBehavior>1</LoadBehavior>
        <CommandPreload>1</CommandPreload>
        <CommandLineSafe>0</CommandLineSafe>
    </Addin>
</Extensibility>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but yes indeed ".Addin" are no longer supported. You need a VSIX project building into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions[Your extension name]". There is not much information on how to extend SSMS 2016 but:

Here is some documentation for VSIX projects: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/extensibility/index

That forum helped me a lot:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1802009/Developing-Extensions-for-SSMS-2016

Hope that helps

Comment: Found this useful:
https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/tree/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox